# Redux state clears after closing (or opening) modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a form using React Native with Redux.
This form has some input fields like title and date.
Furthermore this input field has a modal to select users. Once I am opening and closing the modal the title and date and every other input-field is empty again. I have no idea whether the closing or the opening causes the problem. 
When I went back to another screen and return to the NewEvent-Screen the input fields are still filled out. This only occurs when I open the modal.

```
16:51:23 [exp] Object {
16:51:23 [exp]   "eventTitle": "Tes",
16:51:23 [exp]   "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]     "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]       "eventTitle": "Test123",
16:51:23 [exp]       "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]         "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]           "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]             "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]               "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]                 "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]                   "state": Object {
16:51:23 [exp]                     "eventDate": "no date",
16:51:23 [exp]                     "eventMembers": Array [],
16:51:23 [exp]                     "eventSubtasks": Array [],
16:51:23 [exp]                     "eventTitle": "",
16:51:23 [exp]                   },
16:51:23 [exp]                 },
16:51:23 [exp]               },
16:51:23 [exp]             },
16:51:23 [exp]           },
16:51:23 [exp]         },
16:51:23 [exp]       },
16:51:23 [exp]     },
16:51:23 [exp]   },
16:51:23 [exp] }
16:51:23 [exp] Tes
```

This is what the console shows me when I log the mapStateToProps of the Forms state. Test123 is what I typed in before I opened the modal. However when I close the modal eventTitle is empty again.
I'm new to Redux and I have no idea why it's behaving like this. I need a hint right here because somehow I have difficulties googling the problem.
Thanks for your help.

NewEvent.js

...

```
  closeMultiModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showSelectModal: false });
  }
```

...

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Modal
   animationType="slide"
   transparent={false}
   visible={this.state.showSelectModal}
   >
    <MultiSelect
     closeMultiModal={this.closeMultiModal}
    />
 </Modal>
```

...

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ newEvent }) => {
  const { eventTitle, eventDate } = newEvent;
  console.log(newEvent);
  console.log(eventTitle);
  return { eventTitle, eventDate  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  updateNewEventTitle, updateNewEventDate
})(NewEvent);
```

NewEventActions.js

```
import {
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_TITLE,
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_DATE,
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_MEMBERS,
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_SUBTASKS
} from './types';

export const updateNewEventTitle = (text) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_TITLE,
    payload: text
  };
};

export const updateNewEventDate = (date) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_DATE,
    payload: date
  };
};
```

NewEventReducer.js
// EDIT: This is where the problem is in:

```
import {
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_TITLE,
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_DATE,
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_MEMBERS,
  UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_SUBTASKS
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    eventTitle: '',
    eventDate: 'no date',
    eventMembers: [],
    eventSubtasks: []
 };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_TITLE:
      return { ...state, eventTitle: action.payload };
    case UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_DATE:
      return { ...state, eventDate: action.payload };
    default:
      return { state };
  }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: A console log is not enough to help you... show your code.

Comment: Okay. I thought maybe someone already knew what was wrong by seeing the console.log. Thanks for you comments, I will add my code.

Comment: Feel like we're missing something but I want to say it has to do with the default case in your reducer switch. You're wrapping the default state return in an object, which would at least explain why you're seeing so much nested state action happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reducer is creating that extra set of nesting due to your default case:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_TITLE:
      return { ...state, eventTitle: action.payload };
    case UPDATE_NEW_EVENT_DATE:
      return { ...state, eventDate: action.payload };
    default:
      return { state };
  }
};
```

Change that line to:

```
return state;
```

...otherwise it's going to create an object like this:

```
{
  state: <all the previous state>
}
```

...and will continue nesting state properties for each action that hits the default case.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That solved the issue. I have no idea, why I used the curly braces there. This problem bothered me for quiet a long time so thank you again for helping me. You are awesome!

Answer (score -1):

In your reducer, what about:

From:

```
{ ...state, eventTitle: action.payload }
```

To:

```
{ ...state, {eventTitle: action.payload} }
```

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript.